# Getting two images to show side by side, with some complications

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For my navigation I'm using previous/next buttons. For reasons, these are images, whose CSS sets their background image/height/etc. I am using these throughout my site and they work perfectly, when aligning center.

Now I have these two images but I need them to show up side by side! (with some spacing in between, and the whole shebang centered on the page)

I've tried messing around but whatever I do either makes the images look messed up (eg: trying to use bootstrap columns), or does not get them side by side (eg: traditional inline or whatever). I am okay with having to wrap these in a few divs to get it working, but cannot change the essence of the image's css.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="the-button center-block" />
    <img class="the-button center-block" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.the-button {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/122x42);
    width: 122px;
    padding-left: 122px;
    height: 42px;

    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Should work.

Here is fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/wgrLfxg3/2/

Comment: This was my first idea aswell. However he mentioned not to change the css (thats how I understood it at least) 
'[...] but cannot change the essence of the image's css.'

Comment: Better luck next time.

Comment: @TimHallyburton Yup both of your answers work pretty perfectly, changing my images to inline-block turn out to not break anything!

Comment: Table is kinda 1997, bro.

Comment: Tables vs Divs I preffer using them both because both are good for some thing and bad for some other things. But this is another topic

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <table>
       <tr> 
           <td><img class="the-button center-block" /></td>
           <td><img class="the-button center-block" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try wrapping them into a table. This might just solve your problem.

 It is also easy to modify their spacing that way.
https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/1/

Comment: Who downvoted this? It works exactly like I asked and is a quality answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but while it may solve your problem, it's still bad practice. Tables should be used for tabular data(even then you would still want to use divs in most cases), not for displaying images inline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the padding to center it add margin: 0 auto; and to display them side by side just display inline block.

Here is the code to fix the side by side:

```
.the-button {
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/122x42);
    width: 122px;    
    height: 42px;    
    margin-bottom: 1em;  
}
```

See an example here

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/3/

Do you need to center the buttons in some other div too?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is to just use JavaScript to draw the image over a transparent canvas. So, doing it that way, you will be able to see stuff under it, and you will be able to adjust how big they are, they space between them, where they are, etc.

See these links:

[W3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/canvas)


[html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 310, 470);
ctx.fillRect(320, 5,315, 470);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4errq9r/

It uses rectangles instead of images, but I think it gets thr point across.